# Demoted the Domain Controller and would like to promote again

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

I have demoted the active Directory server "dc01"--running Windows server 2012 r2--and would like to promote it again. I also didn't make a note of what FSMO roles it held before I demoted it.

How do I promote it again and transfer all the FSMO roles back?

Comment: Run DCPROMO and follow the prompts.

Comment: Yeah, but it was primary Domain Controller, have dc01 and dc02, dc01 is the one I demoted and I don't have any backup of its roles, which was installed before. Can I promote it again and have it as primary domain controller.

Comment: There's no such thing as a Primary Domain Controller. If dc01 held the FSMO roles then those were transferred to dc02 during the demotion of dc01. If you want to transfer the FSMO roles back to dc01 after you promote it using DCPROMO then you're free to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately both of them were not connected at the time of demoting dc01, of course I have all the roles on dc02, but how can i promote the dc01 to be primary domain controller and have dc02 as secondary or failover. please advise me

Answer (score 1):

Just go through the normal promotion steps and add the machine to an existing domain. Once it has been promoted go into your AD users and computes, Right click the domain and select Operations Masters. Change these to your DC01 and you are done

Comment: A point of clarification: There are 5 FSMO roles. Only 3 of those can be transferred using ADUC.

Answer (score 1):

If the domain controllers were not able to communicate when you demoted DC01, then you need to take the followings steps. You can google the specifics of each step.

1) Use DC02 to seize the FSMO roles (assuming they belonged to DC01 before the demotion).

2) Clean the orphaned DC from active directory

3) Promote DC01 to a domain controller

4) Move the 5 FSMO roles to DC01 (there are no Primary Domain controller anymore, but this is what most people want when they say they want a DC to be the primary one. If you are thinking along those lines, you might also be interested in reviewing which DC is authoritative for DNS zones and which one does DNS scavenging if it is enabled)